# Full screen overlay on kentico

Tags: kentico, kentico-12

How do to achieve a full height on kentico? I have created a webpart zone and was expecting it to take a ZoneHeight of 100% but that does not work. What is the kentico way of doing this? This is on kentico web forms.

Comment: Where do you want to achieve this?  In the Kentico Admin interface or on the public-facing side of the site?

Comment: public facing side of the site

Comment: I just need a widget zone that takes the entire page and is dynamic for resize, mobile and such

Comment: `height:100wh` & `width:100vw` didn't work for you?